# connect two routers each one with a LAN with a cable (no internet)

Tags: router, network, lan

i want to connect two LANs, each one has a router, to allow pc's to communicate between the two LANs without internet.
i am a complete beginner in networking and i need to make this project urgently. it's supposed to look something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jj02q.jpg . 
how to connect two routers with an ethernet cable? and if possible, can anyone give me the easiest solution to implement the network in the picture.

Comment: What are the router models? How you configure that would depend on the router models. Also, are you going to use static routes or a routing protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want a routed link.

1. Select a network that's not used anywhere like `10.255.254.0/28`.
2. Select two IP addresses from this network, e.g. `10.255.254.1` and `10.255.254.2`.
3. Configure one port on each side with one of them.
4. Connect these two ports.
5. Make each remote network known to the other side by setting either a static route or by using a common routing protocol like OSPF.
6. Set each router as default gateway for all local hosts (you're not going anywhere else without Internet).
7. Enjoy.

Comment: thank you for the well structured answer, how do i connect both routers? using WAN or LAN ports? i dont intend to use internet in any of them